# How to store XML formatted string in a zippped string and store into memory?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me: I have a XML formatted string with me and I want to compress that string and store into memory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need some more background. You have the string with you? Where? In a file on disk? And why keep it compressed in memory (where it cannot be handled because it is compressed)?

Comment: Man, I thought I was the only one with a sore zippped sting.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414037/compressing-strings-for-client-server-transport-in-java

Answer (score 1):

To compress string you should use `ZipOutputStream`. Just create *zip entry* and put your string there. Once it is done your compressed string is in memory.

You can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` that will be wrapped by `ZipOutputStream`. Please refer to apidoc for more details. It is really simple.

Comment: I think ZipOutputStream and ZipInputStream is used to make a zip file on disk. That i dont want I just want to compress a string and store that into memory