# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check

Tags: android, pdf, text-extraction, deflate

My target is to extract raw text from pdf file. I get the byte array but the content is encoded with **FlateDecode** algorithm. So I was trying  to decode the raw content using this code

```
public String readTextFile(Uri uri){

    String mSelectedFilePath = FileUtils.getPath(MainActivity.this,
            uri);
    Log.e(TAG," path "+mSelectedFilePath);


    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        File file = new File(mSelectedFilePath);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e(TAG," line "+line + " "+startStream+" "+startDecode);
                byte[] pText;
                if(line.contains("FlateDecode")){
                    startDecode = true;

                }
                if(line.equals("stream")){
                    startStream = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if(line.equals("endstream")){
                    startDecode = false;
                    startDecode = false;
                }

                if(startDecode && startStream){
                    Log.e(TAG, " inside decode");
                    pText = FLATEDecode(line.getBytes());
                }
                else pText = line.getBytes();
                String res = new String(pText,"UTF-8");
                text.append(res);
                text.append('\n');
                Log.e(TAG,res);
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return text.toString();
```

code for decoding :

```
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();
    decompressor.setInput(src);

    // Create an expandable byte array to hold the decompressed data
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(src.length);

    try {
        while (!decompressor.finished()) {
            int count = decompressor.inflate(buf);
            bos.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        decompressor.end();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    decompressor.end();

    return bos.toByteArray();`
```

But I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:237)
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:214)
```

I know that I can use a library like **itext** or **pdfbox** , but the problem is these library doesn't work well with **bangla** pdf which is my final target. That's why I am trying to build a pdf content extractor from scratch. Here some the raw data  I get from pdf. I want to decode it to get the original data.

```
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 126>>
stream
x�S�P����u�tQ0��SprqVp
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917623/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-zip-dataformatexception-incorrect-header-c'

Comment: I have tried this, but didn't had any luck

Comment: there could be several lines... and it is not a line-based format, between stream and endstream. What you're doing ("build a pdf content extractor from scratch") is a difficult strategy. Rather find out why "these library doesn't work well with bangla pdf". Some PDFs are "immune" to text extraction. Can you do text extraction when using Adobe Reader?

Comment: To stress @Tilman's first point: reading a PDF using character reading operations (e.g. via a `FileReader` or other `Reader` implementation) and then applying `getBytes` is very likely to give you something else than the original bytes, and your replacing every end-of-line by '\n' only worsens this... PDF is a binary format, so treat it like that.

Comment: @Tilman, So far I have seen these libraries don't support indic language like bangla. Thats why I was planning to build one from scratch. and also the pdf is not actually immune, its just instead of "আমার সোনার বাংলা" I get "আমার সিানার বাাংলা আমম স ামায় ভালবামি।"

Comment: @mkl, " PDF is a binary format, so treat it like that." can you please elaborate, or give any link where can I find more information?

Comment: If you build a library from scratch, it will take you several years. PDFBox was started in 2002 and it took until around 2012-2014 to have a good parser. I suggest you look at the source code and specifically, at the PDFTextStripper class.

Comment: The PDF format is described at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf . This does not include the font formats (type 1, CFF and truetype). All together it is probably several 1000 pages.

Comment: "PDF is a binary format, so treat it like that." - *"can you please elaborate"* - You use text oriented I/O. Text oriented I/O assumes a certain character encoding and only works properly for text data with this text encoding (be it ASCII, Latin-1, UTF-8, or whichever). If you apply it to data that is not so encoded text, you will usually damage the data. This is what you do when you call `readTextFile` for a PDF file. You have to not treat the PDF as text, instead you read a PDF file using an `InputStream` or a `RandomAccessFile`, you read the bytes as `byte` or `byte[]` or probably as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `readLine()` on the binary data. Once you've read the length (126) and the line with "stream", then you want to read 126 *bytes of binary data* (starting with the "x" in your example) and feed exactly that to inflate.